# Problem concerning dpkg: file not found

Tags: software-installation

I installed ubuntu 20.04 today and after installing I updated the ubuntu.

I installed other software as well and trying to do that via the terminal, I encountered the problem with `dpkg`.

I needed to go to the folder where the installation package was instaled with following command

```
sudo dpkg -i /pathToFile/....
```

and after entering I got the error message

> "file or folder doesn't exist".

But I downloaded it and copied it in the downloads folder.

Anybody an idea what can I do to find this path in the terminal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are more likely to be able to help if you [edit] your question to show what you *actually* typed (rather than "/pathToFile/...."). As well as what @user535733 noted, there is a difference between an absolute path `/pathToFile` and a relative path like `pathToFile` which may be what is tripping you up.

Comment: Welcome! Could you post the *exact* command you are using? Or better, use tab completion to find the file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't waste your time typing the full path. Use tab completion:

Example, type:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Dow
```

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> (not <kbd>Enter</kbd> afterwards) and it will auto complete the path for you.

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads
```

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice and a list of files will appear.

```
some_file
some_other_file
package_to_install
```

Note that if `package_to_install` is not there, the following won't work

Start typing the name of the file you want to install

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/pack
```

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and it will auto complete the file name.

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/package_to_install
```

Now you can press <kbd>Enter</kbd>